# Message: Unexpected string , while migrating model to mysql db in strongloop

Tags: node.js, migration, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to migrate my model class to mysql db with strongloop tool in node.js loopback framework.

When I click the migrate button it is showing the error

```
Oops! Something is wrong
Unexpected string

Message: Unexpected string
Request: /workspace/api/DataSourceDefinitions/server.mysql/autoupdate
status: 500
```

My model class example

> 

```
{
  "name": "Media",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fileName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

db source file

> 

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mysql": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "mysql://root:12345678@localhost/voice",
    "database": "voice",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "12345678",
    "name": "mysql",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "user": "root"
  }
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Man, you got to at least provide soem code or something, it's saying Unexpected String, how is anybody supposed to know what the string that's wrong is supposed to be if you don't show us............

Comment: Added my model class and database source file , Please check now.